# NewRelic stream & writeHeaders

Tags: newrelic

We are currently evaluating New Relic and there's a trace element I'm not sure I understand correctly '(WPF client and WCF backend) - It usually says 'stream[some url...]writeheaders'. My guess would be the actually transfer of data to the server, however I'm not sure why it says writeheaders?

Comment: Hye jaspernygaard, I have also profilled my WCF services in New Relic, and it shows 'stream[some url...]writeheaders' taking a lot of time. If you get any solution or hint, plz let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is evidence of creating the page headers for [Browser Monitoring](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/browser/new-relic-browser/getting-started/troubleshooting-page-view-monitoring). One interesting thing about this system is that, since New Relic attempts to tie transactions within application code to in-browser performance, every page header grabs an ID from the application monitoring agent.

This system has changed significantly since 2013, so an updated agent may make slightly different calls related to browser monitoring.