# Stream writeheaders take too much time WCF

Tags: performance, wcf, stream, httpwebrequest, newrelic

A similar question is asked at [NewRelic stream & writeHeaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654171/newrelic-stream-writeheaders)

I am profiling my `WCF` services on New Relic. There is a `WCF` service which calls another `WCF` service.
Now I suppose while calling the other WCF service, when it creates request, somewhere the internal process writes headers to request stream which is slow some times. 
The traces I found in New Relic tells me that for a particular method of one of my WCF service which calls a method of my another `WCF` service, takes around `50-60` seconds, out of which `95-100 %` of time is consumed by System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders.

```
Stream[url of WCF service/soap]: WriteHeaders -> 99.78 % time (approx 49 seconds).
```

I am not getting what it is and how to reduce this time ?

I have searched and I didn't found what ConnectStream actually do or some details about it, so that I can find any way to lessen the amount of time its taking.

Please, let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Hi @Deeps, did you have any luck with this issue ? We're also facing the exactly same issue. If yes, could you please share the same. TIA

Comment: Hi texens, Sorry for late reply. No I didn't got any solution till now.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're streaming a large file up from a client, catching it in one WCF web service, then re-writing the data into a new HttpWebRequest, then sending it to another host. I think I'd be tempted to try buffering the data from the client to your web service rather than streaming.

I've spent the last year working on a project that sounds similar to wha you're doing. The difference betweens streaming and buffering is this:

Streaming reads (from source) and then writes (to target) the data in an interative process you don't have much control over. If the source file is large (like a gig or more), the WCF request/response will iterate a dozen or more times back and forth between the client and host before the request is complete.

Buffering, on the other hand, accummulates the entire content of the target file BEFORE filling the request and sending it to the host, thus speeding up the process. And since the performance penalty incurred by buffering (time required to accummulate the bytes in memory) is placed on the client, it's generally not a problem.

So when buffering data from the client, your host you'll receive one Http request with a complete byte array (let's say) that's ready to be repackaged into the request you're passing onto the second, target WCF host. At that point, again, you have the choice between buffering and streaming. On the host, were performance matters, streaming the request to the second host will improve your scalability but (again) potentially hurt your performance speed.

On the client side:

```
    With binding
      .TransferMode =TransferMode.Buffered 'instead of Transfermode.Streamed                                                              
      .MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text
      .TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
      .MaxReceivedMessageSize = Integer.MaxValue
      .ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = Integer.MaxValue
      .ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = Integer.MaxValue
      .ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = Integer.MaxValue
      .ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = Integer.MaxValue
      .ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = Integer.MaxValue
      .MaxBufferSize = Integer.MaxValue
      .MaxBufferPoolSize = Integer.MaxValue
```

On the host side:

```
With binding
      .TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered
      .MaxReceivedMessageSize = Integer.MaxValue
```

Comment: Hi Brian, I am not streaming any large file or something. Its just a WCF service I am requesting to. I have added a Service reference of a WCF service to my project which is also a WCF service. Now I have a method in my service as GetMerchantData(string param1) which gets some values from my database and then calls a method of the service reference added : GetMerchantStoreData(string param1, string param2, string param3). The request looks like:

Comment: MyServiceRefClient client =  new MyServiceRefClient();                    var result = client.GetMerchantStoreData(param1, param2, param3);       and then I return this result from my service.                             This result object contains 12 properties. I don't think its a large data, or any streaming. What I think it is related to writing some default headers while making a request to ssl hosted wcf service. But I can't figure out what I can do to reduce this time. Because I haven't written this line Stream[url of WCF service/soap]: WriteHeaders in my code anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: I understand. Sorry I couldn't help further.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same thing before when the service you're calling is stalling or is flooded with  too many concurrent connections.  If the issue is the former, profiling your WCF service may help identify the root cause -- maybe it's slow to respond due to database access or some other I/O bound process.  If the issue is the later, it may be something that you can resolve by tuning the performance of the service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377061(v=bts.10).aspx)

This can also manifest itself as "BeginRequest" for an ASP.NET application in New Relic.  Rarely does BeginRequest or WriteHeaders mean the problem is really with sending the data itself, though it could be if you have large payloads, but in regular calls where the data transmitted is small, the problem with a slow time to connect or slow response will appear in these two areas.